# Graph API is not working via project code but same URL is working via AD Graph Explorer

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have download a MVC application from Git for AAD graph API. I ran this application but each time i am not getting expected result.

To find the error i run same api using postman and generated token below was the response.

```
   {
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Resource not found for the segment 'me'."
    }
  }
}
```

I am using below Get URL-

```
https://graph.windows.net/XXXXX/me?api-version=1.6
```

Also, to verify is it working with [AAD Grapg api explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net). After log in everything is working fine.

Below is my code to call Grapg API-

```
 // Get the access token from the cache
            string userObjectID =
                ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")
                    .Value;

            string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

            //AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority,
            //    new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true);
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId.ToString(), credential);
            var Token = result.AccessToken;
            //// AcquireTokenSilentAsync
            //result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, credential,
            //    new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

            // Call the Graph API manually and retrieve the user's profile.
            string requestUrl = String.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                graphUserUrl,
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tenantId));
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // Return the user's profile in the view.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(responseString);
            }
```

Could you guys please tell me what is the problem with my code. Why it is working on AAD explorer not with Localhost.

Comment: Can you share your access token (after obfuscating sensitive information)? You want to make sure to be using an access token with User Context, otherwise the Graph API wouldn't know who "me" is.

Answer (score 0):

To request the `me` endpoint of Azure AD Graph REST, we need to use the delegate token which represents the sign-in user.

The code above you acquire token using the **Client Credential flow** is request the access token which represents for the application which doesn't contain the info of sign-in user.

To achieve this in the MVC application, we need to acquire the token after you get the authorization code when users login. Next time, we can acquire the token from the token cache based on the login user.

Here is the code for your reference( code sample from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web)):

```
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, credential,
                new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

Comment: Thanks Fei for reply, i did try this code as well but using this code i am not able to generate token. When i use above code i am getting exception. Is there anything missing. 

Also, i have download same project from git and configure as per our AAD.

Comment: I have created different thread for that problem that you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586897/authcontext-acquiretokensilentasync-throwing-error)

Comment: What's the error message you got? Are you able to get the access token when users sign-in in the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` code of `Startup` class?

Comment: @OnkarrajAmbatwar Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I caught up in some other work, due to that i kept this on hold. I will try this over the weekend and let you know.