# authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync throwing error

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have taken reference from [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/) git project. This project has code to connect and get information about User Profile.

While running the project i saw i am not able to get successful result from below code-

```
                result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, credential,
                new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

Here is full code-

```
 // Get the access token from the cache
            string userObjectID =
                ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")
                    .Value;

            string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

            //AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority,
            //    new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true);

            // AcquireTokenSilentAsync
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, credential,
                new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

            // Call the Graph API manually and retrieve the user's profile.
            string requestUrl = String.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                graphUserUrl,
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tenantId));
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // Return the user's profile in the view.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(responseString);
            }
```

I tired replacing **UserIdentifierType.UniqueId** with **UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId** but still not able to get successful result.

After trying all day long, i am not able to figure it out the solution of this.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Acquiring a token silently requires that you have the access token cached at that time. Or the refresh token in which case it can fetch new tokens silently. Has the user logged in at this point?

Comment: Yes, user is logged in to the application.

Comment: Please try the code with default account(`demoUser@graphDir1.onMicrosoft.com graphDem0`) provide by this code sample without change the code. And if you want to use your own tenant, please follow the [instruction](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web) how to run this code sample.

Comment: @OnkarrajAmbatwar Any update for this issue?

Comment: Any updated on this question ? i'm also facing the same issue .